# Extracting information from Shapiro.test() in R

Tags: r

I am using `shapiro.test()` in R to test the normality of a data set. I want to extract the w-statistic and p-value from it so that I can use it somewhere. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Look at str(shapiro.test(rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3)))

Answer (score 5):

```
results <- shpairo.test(valuesToTest)
results$p.value
```

Comment: This works for p value. How to get w-statistic value

Answer (score 4):

```
> data(iris)
> stest <- shapiro.test(iris$Petal.Width)
> stest$p.value
## [1] 1.68024e-08
> stest$statistic
##        W 
## 0.901834
```